# Unity unresponsive on applying material on probuilder model

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was making a big project in unity, it had photon multiplayer system, a probuilder model, a character for player(fps). everything works totally fine in the development build. however when I thought of editing a building which was made with probuilder by using materials. the editor crashes the moment I apply a material to any component of that building. it is a very complex building with many edge loops, faces, etc. etc. The editor does not work again so I need to force stop it. It seems as if the the model is slowing it down but I am not a pro so I don't know exactly. Please give a solution. I have already tried disabling auto refresh and compressing assets.